# Best way to implement concurrent operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have two lists containing strings  of varying length. I need to compare the two list to each other using an algorithm lets say AlgorithmX that will determine if string in ListA should be kept. The lists is quite long (over 50 000 items per list) and the length can vary from 1 char to 5000 chars.

So we looking at a minimum of 50 000 * 50 000 comparisons (and its not direct comparisons, each string from the list gets put through AlgorthmX

Now my multithreading knowledge is rather low. But I have been reading up on it. However there are various implementations of it in .Net. Standard threading, Tasks, await async.

What would be the be the best approach to having the lists compared using AlgorithmX using multithreading? i.e Should I use await async, Task Library?

Should I split ListA's items equally per CPU and run the algorithm against ListB? Should I use concurrentQueue on the split lists?

[EDIT]
ConcurrentQueue seems to be what Im looking for .. but any additions are welcome
http://www.erikbergman.net/2016/03/17/high-speed-applications-parallelism-in-net-part-2/

Any pointers will be welcome!

Comment: Is AlgorithmX just an intersection or something more complicated?

Comment: So you're not modifying either ListA or ListB?   and you're looking to use the ConcurrentQueue to store the results of those strings to be kept?

Answer (score 1):

A possible implementation which uses `ConcurrentQueue` to store those strings which the algorithm decides to keep *(Note: There's no particular reason not to use some other thread-safe collection)*.

This approach uses [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) to iterate through `ListA`:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var listA = new[] {"the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"};
    var listB = new List<string>(new[] {"fox", "dog", "cat", "mouse"});
    var stringsToKeep = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    Parallel.ForEach(listA, a =>
    {
        var shouldKeep = AlgorithmX(a, listB);
        if (shouldKeep)
        {
            stringsToKeep.Enqueue(a);
        }
    });

    Console.WriteLine($"Matching strings: {string.Join(", ", stringsToKeep.ToArray())}");
}
```

*Assumptions:*

1. There is no requirement for either  `ListA` nor `ListB` to be modified while the comparisons take place.   As long as these aren't being modified, there are no issues with concurrent access (read-only access to a `List<>` is fine in a multi-threaded environment - concurrency issues only arise when a list is modified - e.g. Insert/Delete/etc. ).
2. `AlgorithmX` has no side-effects (i.e. the method is "pure" and therefore thread-safe - able to be called concurrently with no issues)
3. The order of the strings in `ListA` does not need to be reflected in the results (i.e. you don't care about the ordering of the strings which the algorithm decides to keep).

Comment: This would have been my first approach as well. Probably partitioning would make sense. Hard to say. At the end it needs experimenting with real data and the real algorithm,

Answer (score 0):

> However there are various implementations of [multithreading] in .Net. Standard threading, Tasks, await async.
>
> What would be the be the best approach to having the lists compared using AlgorithmX using multithreading? i.e Should I use await async, Task Library?

If you take a step back, you can see that `async`/`await` is not appropriate here. "Concurrency" is doing more than one thing at a time. Asynchrony is a form of concurrency that does *not* use dedicated threads for its operation - you can think of it as more event-based. Parallelism is a form of concurrency that uses *multiple* threads for its operation. Asynchrony and parallelism are both forms of concurrency, but they're opposites when it comes to implementation details. For this reason, asynchrony is normally used for I/O-bound or other non-CPU-related tasks like timers; parallelism is normally used for CPU work like running a computational algorithm a million times.

Regarding parallelism, then, there are [a few tools you have available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553.aspx). Generally speaking, it's best to use the tool with the highest abstraction. Manual threads are right out, as is using the thread pool directly.

In your case, you want to use either `Parallel` or Parallel LINQ, both of which build on top of the Task Parallel Library, which in turn uses the thread pool.

There's a [great answer using `Parallel` already](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43559385/263693), but I find that if you need to have *results* of an operation, Parallel LINQ often results in simpler code. In this case:

```
static List<string> RunAlgorithm(List<string> listA, List<string> listB)
{
  return listA.AsParallel()
      .Where(a => AlgorithmX(a, listB)).ToList();
}
```

This code has the same limitations as the `Parallel.ForEach` code in the other answer (i.e., lists are not modified during `RunAlgorithm`, `AlgorithmX` is threadsafe, and the order of the resulting strings is not preserved).

Parallel LINQ is a bit nicer when it comes to parallel algorithms with outputs, and has some additional helpers specifically for managing those outputs. For example, preserving the original order:

```
static List<string> RunAlgorithm(List<string> listA, List<string> listB)
{
  return listA.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
      .Where(a => AlgorithmX(a, listB)).ToList();
}
```